# Question about inheritance within the namespace through derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

I have a base class which does not reside in any namespace. I would like to derive from that class with the same class name inside a namespace. I used the scope resolution operator to do that. However, I am questioning the way my code is structured and need some guidance regarding accesses.

I have done the following

class_B.cpp

```
class class_A; //Forward declaration
class_B
{
public:
  class_A * var; 
};
```

class_A.h

```
class class_A {};
```

my_project.h

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    class class_A : public ::class_A {}; //Deriving from global class_A
    class class_D : public class_B {}; 
}
```

What derivation of `var` is expected from `class_D`? Is it going to represent the base `class_A`, or the namespace-derived `class_A`?

Comment: You did notice, that `class_A * var;` scope is private, didn't you?

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_D` has base class `::class_B` which contains pointer on `::class_A`.

The other `my_namespace::class_A` doesn't interfere with `::class_B`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to enforce `class_D::class_B` pointer to use `my_namespace:class_A` pointer instead of `::class_A` while within the namespace?

Comment: You might have templated `class_B` to allow to have `::class_A` or `my_namespace:class_A` ... or any other classes. You cannot enforce to use the `class_A` from namespace of derived class.